# Trying to install call flow application ... keeps failing

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, voip, sip

Has anyone tried to install callflow?
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Callflow

I downloaded the tar file and extracted everything to:

/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180$

I followed the first set of instructions in the INSTALL file and ended up with:

```
jj@joshua:~/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/build$ sudo find / -name callflow*
/callflow
/callflow/callflow.conf
/usr/local/bin/callflow
/usr/local/share/callflow
/usr/local/share/callflow/js/callflow.js
/usr/local/share/callflow/css/callflow.css
/usr/local/share/callflow/scripts/callflow.awk
/usr/local/share/man/man1/callflow.1
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/js/callflow.js
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/callflow
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/css/callflow.css
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/conf/callflow.conf
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/man/callflow.1
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/scripts/callflow.awk
/home/jj/Downloads/callflow-20120624-180.tar.bz2
/home/jj/.local/share/Trash/info/callflow.trashinfo
/home/jj/.local/share/Trash/files/callflow
/share/doc/callflow
```

When i try to run the file in the bin folder, I get an error message:

**callflow: error: setup
directory "/usr/local/callflow" does not exist Adjust your configuration**

I've searched and I see that it installed / created 2 conf files:

```
jj@joshua:~/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/build$ sudo find / -name callflow.conf
/callflow/callflow.conf
/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/conf/callflow.conf
jj@joshua:~/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/build$
```

They both have the set up directory set to /home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180

I don't really know what I'm supposed to do to get this going...
any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install `callflow` system wide to solve your problem. Actually you don"t even need to call `cmake`.

> This is a collection of awk and shell scripts that will take a capture
>   file that can be read by tshark and produce a callflow sequence
>   diagram

There's nothing to compile, `callflow` returned an error because $SETUPDIR is not defined.

you can start callflow this way:

```
SETUPDIR=. ./callflow -h
```

For better results of course edit your `conf/callflow.conf` to fix the `SETUPDIR` path to be `/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180` instead of `/usr/local/callflow`.

Now edit the `callflow` bash script (line 5) to replace the default CONFDIR value:

```
CONFDIR="/etc/callflow";
```

by

```
CONFDIR="/home/jj/Documents/callflow-20120624-180/conf";
```

Now you can run it from source:

```
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Downloads/callflow-20120624-180$ ./callflow -h
Usage: callflow [options] <filename>
See callflow --help for extended help.
```

Answer (score 1):

Download source code and extract:

```
cd <where_you_downloaded_the_sources>
tar xvf callflow-20120624-180.tar.bz2 (change with your version file)
```

then configure with:

```
cd callflow-20120624-180/ (or the folder create by tar)
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR=/etc
```

this install conf file in `/etc/callflow/`.

Install:

```
sudo make install
```

Now, refer to `/etc/callflow/callflow.conf` (in the first lines):

```
# SETUPDIR, default /usr/local/callflow
SETUPDIR="/usr/local/callflow"
```

create this folder:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/callflow
```

or change `SETUPDIR` with existing folder, ie `/home/<your_home>/callflow`

You should now be able to run the program, typing:

```
callflow
```

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions in the `INSTALL` file, then you just need to create that folder:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/callflow
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that from reading the INSTALL.  which section are you referring to?  I tried creating that directory but that didn't resolve the issue... I'm revisiting the install again, just to be sure... thanks.

Comment: So even after creating that directory you still get the same error? I followed all the steps in INSTALL (just replaced `make install` with `checkinstall` to create a deb package instead) and it seems to work (I don't get any error, just it asking for a file)

Comment: yeah... it still fails.  I created that directory and then tried to start the application again.  but it's still a no go

Answer (score 0):

You should tray a new version **callflow-20141023.tar.bz2** from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/callflow/files/callflow/). Some bug has been removed. I made some test with SIP pcap file and it seems to work (at least with this type of messages). One think - it is important to set up `$FILTER` .

For example

1. `export $FILTER=sip`
2. `slawek@kodeina:~/src$ callflow Register.pcap`

   ```
   tshark started
   ** (process:20338): WARNING **: Preference "column.format" has been converted to     "gui.column.format"
   Save your preferences to make this change permanent.
   DPI: 90
      Background RRGGBBAA: ffffffff
      Area 0:0:1425:772 exported to 1425 x 772 pixels (90 dpi)
      Bitmap saved as: Register/callflow.png
      callflow: bz2 archive available at "Register/Register.tar.bz2"
      The output can be viewed with a browser:
      firefox Register/index.html
   ```